# Jupyter Notebook debugging not working on VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscode-debugger, jupyter-kernel

I'm trying to activate the **debugging** functions that are now available on **VSCode** for **Jupyter Notebooks** but I'm having some problems with that.

In my interface I can see the button to '*Run by Line*' next to every cell but when I click it **nothing happens** except the normal execution of the entire cell, but that mode is supposed to execute your cell **line by line**... I've tried putting some breakpoints even I know it is not necessary in that mode but still **nothing**.

As you can see here the buttons for debugging are shown a few seconds after hitting the '*Run by Line*' button but they do nothing.

[image]

As a workaround to not being able to use that useful mode, I tried the standard debug mode of **VSCode** for **Jupyter Notebooks** which let you go **breakpoint to breakpoint** on your cell, the problem (I think it is) is that when I use that what **VSCode** does is open **another tab** with just the code of the cell I'm debugging in a **temporary** `.py` file, which is not the behaviour I would like to have, because I think it should do that on the Notebook tab **itself** without any new file...

Here I show you a screenshot of the **temporary** `.py` that it's created:

[image]

That's just the code of my notebook first cell!

Any help with this? I would like to solve **both problems** or at least one of them.
I've checked the requisites for the debug modes and make sure **I fullfill everyone of them** but I'm not so used to use the debug functionalities of VSCode so maybe I'm skipping something.

Comment: Same phenomenon as yours and no more information in [Debug a Jupyter Notebook](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_debug-a-jupyter-notebook). You may ask in github for more help.

Comment: I did it, I opened an issue, if you can [go check it](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8250) and let a comment to let them know it is not unusual it would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

This is a current bug. It was notified to the dev team here:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8258

The bug is caused by vscode using a shortened username. In my case GUILLE~1 instead of Guillermo.

The current solution available is to create a **new user in your computer with a maximum length of 8 characters.**